# Enterprise Architect: How to change type of element?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have an element which is created as a table. In the "Element Properties" window, I see the `Type` is `Class` and `Stereotype` is `table`. For other similar tables, the `Type` is `Table` and `Stereotype` is `table`. Something seems to be icky with this particular instance.

[image: Incorrect table]

[image: Correct table]

However, when I run the following script

```
var element as EA.Element;
element = Repository.GetTreeSelectedObject();
Session.Output(element.Type);
```

The result is (for both tables!) `Class`. I thought to outsmart the EA UI by programmatically setting the type, but as both tables (the OK table and the "broken" table) both produce `Class` when asked for the `.Type`, I'm hesitant to set the `.Type` using a script.

I have thought about removing this table and re-adding a new one, but this is tedious as the table has a lot of connections.

How to change the Type of this particular "broken" table to "Table"?

Comment: FWIW: The Type is the Metatype assigned to an element. You can change the metatype with a stereotype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that both «table» stereotypes are not the same.

The one where the type indicates Table is the correct one.
The other one is a *rogue* one.

Steps to solve this:

- Remove the rogue stereotype from the internal stereotype list **Configure | Reference Data | UML Types** (to prevent the problem from happening again)
- Change the stereotype from the problematic element to the stereotype «table» from the UML profile EAUML. In a script you can do this by setting the property `EA.Element.StereotypeEx` to the qualified name: **EAUML::table**). Manually you can use the [...] button to select the correct stereotype from the correct profile.

Comment: Nice! Just... How do I know which one is the rogue stereotype? I have one with base class "class" and base class "component".

Comment: Delete both, they are both rogue stereotypes. The "good" one is not in this list.

Comment: I have set the stereotype EAUML::table in the stereotype field of the properties pane of the element. This did the trick.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know you could type in the fully qualified stereotype in the properties.